# How to write unit tests for angularjs project using cypress

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, cypress, istanbul, nyc

I am new to cypress and I want to write unit tests for my existing application. Can anyone suggest how to write unit tests for angular js using cypress and code coverage?

I have followed the documentation but I am not getting combined results. The code coverage index file is showing only spec files.

https://i.postimg.cc/FH0fnRrM/Screen-Shot-2020-11-09-at-10-53-56-AM.png

https://i.postimg.cc/wjkNjvCh/Screen-Shot-2020-11-09-at-10-54-45-AM.png

Comment: Have you checked the [official documentation](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/15/control-angular-application-from-e2e-tests/)?

Comment: Yes I have checked the official documentation but the code coverage is not showing combined results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these plugins:

For angular

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angular-unit-test

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angularjs-unit-test

For code coverage

https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage

I also recommend that you read this article:

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/03/20/angular-cypress-love/